# Unity fails to build Android player, gives ambigous error

Tags: unity, c#, android

I'm trying to build an android player, (worked like a charm yesterday), and I'm getting a single error when it fails

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 2 seconds (2401 ms)
Building Player failed
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I looked into Editor logs, and it gives me the following stack trace:

```
UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I am totally lost on the fix. I haven't installed any new packages , just fixed few bugs I found after testing yesterday's build.

Version of Unity: 2022.3.4f1

P.S. Building for Windows works normal. I restarted unity, restarted my PC, I cleared project meta data, and reset player settings, tried different combinations of build settings also, there is no compilation errors in scripts.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This looks like the summary statement at the end of the log, not the root problem that caused the build to fail. Do you see any other errors or warnings higher up in the log?

Comment: @DMGregory Nope, the only thing I can see is ```[W] Failed to delete "Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\AsyncPluginsFromLinkerSymbols" (recursively): Access Denied.``` I tried running Unity as an admin and it still won't build.